# the scope of spring configuration xml files on different maven modules

Tags: xml, spring, maven, module, scope

Example:
I have two Maven modules, module A contains the DAO classes for accessing the database and the module B is the service which depence on module A and provides methods for accessing the data.

The XML file in module A activates Spring to use the annotation driven transactions:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

does that mean i can use the transaction annotations (@Transactional) in module B?? How can i see that the annotations are not just ignored ?

thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the Maven dependencies are wired correctly it should not matter that the DAO is in different JAR from the service class.  You can use your integration test to convince yourself that annotations aren't being ignored.

[UPDATE]
**SomeTest.java**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:applicationContext.xml"})
public class SomeTest {
  @Autowired EmployeeService employeeService;
  @Test 
  public final void addEmployee() throws Exception {
    employeeService.addEmployee(new Employee("John Doe"));
  }
}
```

**EmployeeService.java**

```
@Service("employeeService")
public class EmployeeService() {
  @Autowired private EmployeeDao employeeDao;

  @Transactional
  public void addEmployee(final Employee employee) {
    employeeDao.insert(employee);
  }
}
```

All the above is in the module that contains the service.  The DAO comes from another JAR as you have described.

Comment: what do you mean with integration test? Could you give me an example how to test for the annotation usage? Im relatively new to spring.. =/

Answer (score 3):

The scope of `<tx:annotation-driven>` and other similar declarations is an [application context](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-basics).

If XML files from different modules are used by a single application context, `<tx:annotation-driven>` is applied to all beans in that context. Otherwise, if each module creates its own application context, you need to declare `<tx:annotation-driven>` in each of them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer =) but i don't really get it, so what in that correlation is the application context? Project A (DAO) has an XML file with activated "annotation-driven" and project B does have no XML but uses annotations, does it work or not?